# Checking if NSTimer was added to NSRunLoop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer, nsrunloop

Let's say I'm creating NSTimer in some place in the code and later, I want to add it to the mainRunLoop only if it wasn't already added before:

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                target:self
                                                selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
```

Another place in the code:

```
if("my myTimer wasn't added to the mainRunLoop")
{
    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop];
    [runLoop addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

Is there a way to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
CFRunLoopRef loopRef = [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] getCFRunLoop];
BOOL timerAdded = CFRunLoopContainsTimer(loopRef, (CFRunLoopTimerRef)myTimer ,kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
```

then check `timerAdded` variable

Answer (score 2):

Yes; keep a reference to it in an instance variable and check for non-`nil`:

```
@interface MyClass() {
    NSTimer *_myTimer;
}
@end

...

if (!_myTimer)
{
    _myTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                       target:self
                                     selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                                     userInfo:nil
                                      repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop];
    [runLoop addTimer:_myTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

Comment: after creating the timer, _myTimer != nil .   The are two places in code from where later, I want to add it to the run loop. But I want to add it only once.

Comment: To the same run loop?

Comment: Yes - To the same run loop.

Comment: Then my answer will work; you know that once it's created it's added to the runloop immediately.  If you want to remove it from the runloop then also invalidate `_myTimer` and set it to `nil` and it can be re-added again.

Comment: This is how I always do it: if the thing exists then it's attached. No need to retain a created but not running timer.